# How to set column defaults for linked tables?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, default-value, ms-access-2016, linked-tables

In my access 365 database, I am linking some tables of my sql server 2017.

An example table in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE pet (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'noname',
    age INT DEFAULT 1
)
```

[image: Sql Server table definition]

If I link it, the columns "name" and "age" do not have a default value in the table design view.

[image: Ms Access]

How can I link sql server tables into my accdb Access database, and use all of it's defaults?

(This worked fine in Access 2002 with the .ADP-file format)

Comment: I have no idea why default property setting not carrying over through link. Might just have to set this property of control in form design.

Comment: Access for some reason does not show the default value when linked table but since the data is stored on SQL server the default value is granted there.

Comment: @Vlado In unsaved forms, displaying new records, it would be useful for the users to already see the default values filled in.